# Batch to assign filename with spaces to variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, scripting

Many apologies if this has been answered but I've searched for a week to get this right and to no avail.  I'm trying to create a batch file that looks in a folder for a specific file ext (there will only ever be one), assigns the name of that file to a variable, and then renames the file based on the variable name to a new name.

What I have so far:

```
for /F %%x in ('dir /b *.html') do set "FileName=%%x"
echo %FileName%
ren %FileName% test.html
```

Because each filename is going to have spaces in it, this solution will only assign the first word of the filename to `%FileName%` and thus the rename line will not work because it won't find a filename in the folder with `<<FirstWordofFilename>>.html`

My question is, how do I assign a name with spaces in it to a variable?

Again, apologies if this has been answered, I really couldn't find it anywhere despite it having to be a common problem.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you could easily do what you need simply with `for %%x in (*.html) do set filename=%%x`. For the rename, just put it in quotes: `ren "%filename%" test.html`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /F "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b *.html') do set "FileName=%%x"
echo "%FileName%"
ren "%FileName%" "test.html"
```

See

```
for /?
```

from the prompt for more info.